# Converting confidence interval to SE for Ln(rate ratio)

Tags: standard-error, meta-analysis, incidence-rate-ratio

I have the following a data for a medical meta-analysis. The data is given as an annualized flare rate for the drug and placebo, and then the rate ratio (0.67) is presented with a confidence interval. I am using the ln(rate ratio) for an inverse variance analysis on RevMan 5.4. But how do I convert these confidence intervals into a standard error for the rate ratio? [image: Annualized flare rate, given as a rate ratio between the drug and placebo]

I saw the Cochrane Handbook has the formula (upper limit- lower limit)/3.92 = SE. Can I input this as an SE along with the ln (rate ratio) or do I take the ln(SE) and use it?

Comment: You should convert everything to the log scale (estimate + confidence limits) and then proceed as usual.